# Hours and seconds are lost when storing a date in the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, jdbc

I'm storing a date (java.util.date) in an mysql database, before storage I have

```
Mon Feb 11 18:17:41 CET 2013
```

after storage just :

```
2013-02-11 00:00:00.0
```

The database field was declared this way :

```
`DATE_CREATION` date DEFAULT NULL,
```

and I'm using a  InnoDB engine

What can I do to avoid loosing the time?
thanks.

Comment: `DATE` is not a `TIMESTAMP` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: Gosh, if only this were...[documented in some way](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html - change the data type in MySQl to DATETIME.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATETIME` data type instead of `DATE` for the column definition.